# Average Line of Several Lines in 3D (Is it Possible?)

Tags: geometry

How do you get the average line of many/several lines (at least 3 lines), in 3D? Is that possible? I'm trying to reconstruct a track out of the lines that I have generated. I obtained these lines from two points in 3D space.

Comment: What is meant by average? Suppose two lines are skew and at shortest distance $d$, and their generating vectors are at angle $\theta$, then what will be called average line? One that is midway between them and at half the angle?

Comment: Initially, I have three points. From these three points, the lines are obtained by two of the points, 1 line from points 1 and 2, 1 line from points 2 and 3, and 1 line from point 1 and 3. I wanted to get the average of these lines. Well, that was suggested to me, so I kind of asked if it's possible. I'm working on a detector and I'm reconstructing the tracks of my particles as it passes through different modules.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines are data points with $(x,y,z)$ coordinates for each timestep, then simply take the mean of all $x$  given for one timestep and so on.

Another approach for data points is to use a regression if you already have an idea what the mathematical equation is for every curve but the curves are noisy because of measurement accuracy and uncertainty of the system.

If your lines are given by a parametric description $(x_i(t),y_i(t),z_i(t))$, then you simply create a new parametic line given by $1/N(\sum x_i(t),\sum y_i(t),\sum z_i(t))$, in which $N$ is the number of curves you want to avarage.